# Matching a string with a regex gives null even though it should match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get my regex to work in JavaScript, but I have a problem.

**Code**:

```
var reg = new RegExp('978\d{10}');
var isbn = '9788740013498';
var res = isbn.match(reg);

console.log(res);
```

However, res is always `null` in the console.

This is quite interesting, as the regex should work.

My question: then, what is the right syntax to match a string and a regex?

(If it matters and could have any say in the environment: this code is taken from an `app.get` view made in `Express.js` in my `Node.js` application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using a string to build your regex, you need to escape the `\`. It's currently working to escape the `d`, which doesn't need escaping.

You can see what happens if you create your regex on the chrome console:

```
new RegExp('978\d{10}');
// => /978d{10}/
```

Note that there is no `\d`, only a `d`, so your regex matches `978dddddddddd`. That is, the literal `'d'` character repeated 10 times.

You need to use `\\` to insert a literal `\` in the string you're building the regex from:

```
var reg = new RegExp('978\\d{10}'); 
var isbn = '9788740013498';
var res = isbn.match(reg);

console.log(res)

// => ["9788740013498", index: 0, input: "9788740013498"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape with double back slash if you use RegExp constructor:

```
var reg = new RegExp('978\\d{10}');
```

Quote from [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are necessary. For example, the following are equivalent:

```
var re = /\w+/;
var re = new RegExp("\\w+");
```